# getBoundingClientRect() causes javascript to crash?

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

So I am trying to scrape a captcha image off a page using the following code within my phantom.js

```
if(page.content.search('captcha') != -1){
    console.log('taking a picture')
    var clipRect = document.querySelector("img[id='auth-captcha-image']").getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log('got bounds')
    page.clipRect = {
        top:    clipRect.top,
        left:   clipRect.left,
        width:  clipRect.width,
        height: clipRect.height
    };
    page.render('capture.png');
  }
```

As you can see its pretty straight forward. Get the element, get clip to the bounds of the element and then take a screenshot of the render.

Now when I execute

```
document.querySelector("img[id='auth-captcha-image']").getBoundingClientRect()
```

within the google chrome console it returns this.

```
ClientRect {top: 430, right: 621, bottom: 500, left: 421, width: 200…}
```

However within my javascript code it seems to be producing some sort of error that I cannot catch. When I remove the suffix ".getBoundingClientRect()" the code starts working. (obviously I have to add dummy values in for the clipRect dimensions).

I dont quite understand how it is crashing and how to even see the stacktrace/error message of the crash..

Any help would be amazing
Thanks

Comment: any chance you can put together a plunker/jsFiddle/snippet? This is an interesting problem

Comment: how can you fiddle phantomjs?

Comment: What do you mean by “some sort of error”? You can see any error in the browser console (by pressing F12). What does it say?

Comment: @Xufox: there is no F12/browser console here...

Comment: what version of phantomjs are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Any and all javascript that has to do with the target page's DOM must be executed inside page.evaluate() function.

```
var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector("img[id='auth-captcha-image']").getBoundingClientRect();
});
```